# How to get class name in nested fluentvalidation validators

Tags: .net-core, fluentvalidation

I am trying to implement a complex nested validator using FluentValidation in .Net Core. Suppose there's a failure in one of the nested validators and the error messages are available at `validationResult.Errors`. I was wondering if is there a way that I can access the name of the object that has the error.

### Entities

**Constituent**

```
public class Constituent : BaseAuditedEntity
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ClientProspectID { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Client")]
    public virtual ICollection<Solicit> Solicits { get; set; }
}
```

**Solicit**

```
public class Solicit: BaseAuditedEntity
{
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public long ClientId { get; set; }

    public StudyType StudyType { get; set; }

    public virtual Constituent Client { get; set; }
}
```

### Validators

**ConstituentValidator and its nested SolicitValidator**

```
public class ConstituentValidator : AbstractValidator<Constituent>
    {
        public ConstituentValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.ClientProspectID).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Invalid ClientProspectID");
            RuleForEach(x => x.Solicits).SetValidator(new SolicitValidator());
        }

        class SolicitValidator : AbstractValidator<Solicit>
        {
            public SolicitValidator()
            {
                RuleFor(x => x.StudyType).NotEqual(StudyType.Invalid).WithMessage("Invalid StudyType");
            }
        }
    }
```

Just to highlight the question, in the case of failing the validation rule, is there a way that I can find which main or nested validator has failed.

```
var validationResult = validator.Validate(item);
if (!validationResult.IsValid)
{
    invalidData.AddRange(validationResult.Errors.Select(q => new DataImportValidationResult
    {
        DataImportId = dataImportData.Id,
        ClientProspectID = item.ClientProspectID,
        ValidationResult = q.ErrorMessage,
        AttemptedValue = q.AttemptedValue.ToString(),
        Field = q.PropertyName,
        Category = "", //Here I need a way to find which object has failed.
    }));                            
   }
```

If it is not possible to access the failed object, is there a way that we can set a property in the validations rule that can be accessible in the *validationResult* errors?

Comment: This will give you class name . Category = item.GetType().Name

Comment: Nope, this return "ValidationFailure"

Comment: Maybe item.ClientProspectID.GetType()

Comment: if you notice I am looking to find it in "validationResult" and as long as its type is "ValidationFailure" it won't contain any useful information.

Comment: Are you unable to validate the `StudyType` attribute normally or are there other problems?

Comment: I am trying to find out at which class the violation happened? The validation failure might happen either in Constituent or Solicit classes as their validators are nested, and the name of the class that its validation rule has failed is what I am looking for.